# Manually install Gradle plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle, installation

For reasons out of my control I'm unable to resolve plugins from the internet. I want to know how can I manually install the plugins I need so gradle finds them.

I found the .gradle folder and I assume they'll be downloaded there, but have no idea where I should put them.

Any help is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [How to make Gradle repository point to local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965901/how-to-make-gradle-repository-point-to-local-directory), we can use

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}
```

or

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url 'file://D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}
```

and put all *.jar and *.pom files into this directory.

If you write not absolute path, it will be resolved relatively folder with this gradle file.

Also there is a note: **flatDir** repository doesn't support transitive dependency resolution, while **maven** local repository does.

Answer (score 3):

The gradle cache in .gradle is a bit finicky, and not really meant to be changed manually. See some additional information about making gradle cache portable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973244/745574

Maybe the best way to cache plugins offline is to find a way to add the plugin binaries to you local .m2 folder - maven cache is more forgiving of copy pasting files.