# How to Import local npm package in gradle/kotlin

Tags: node.js, kotlin, gradle, npm

I want to call a local npm package in my kotlin project. At first, I tried to call a package from the npm repository using the below steps. Let's take an example of is-sorted package which checks the array whether it is sorted or not and returns a boolean value.

1. Add the dependencies in build.gradle.kts
   `implementation(npm("is-sorted","1.0.0"))`
2. Create an "is-sorted.kt" file under main->kotlin. Add the below annotations and function along with
   its return type.
   `@JsModule("is-sorted")`

   `@JsNonModule`

   `external fun <T> sorted(a: Array<T>): Boolean`
3. Now under main function we have to add our print or test statement.

But when I am trying to add my local package in gradle using the same and adding it's path

`implementation(npm("C:\\hitesh-kotlin-module","1.0.0"))`

After the build, I am getting the below error.

`Package "C:\\hitesh-kotlin-module" refers to a non-existing file '"C:\\hitesh-kotlin-module@1.0.0"'.`

Does anyone know how to resolve this error and how to import a local npm package in gradle?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965901/how-to-make-gradle-repository-point-to-local-directory

Comment: Above is not a dublicate