# When working on a project and one of it's dependency in parallel how to load it from the file system

Tags: gradle, local

I'm working on a java dependency that I publish on GitLab via gradle. In parallel I also work on some projects dependent of it.

When I need to do a change in the parent I have to wait for my CI/CD to be over before I can keep developing the childs. There is most certainly a way to tell gradle 'check there before online' but all I've found until now is to do that with local jar but not raw source files.

I tried most of the things in [How to make Gradle repository point to local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965901/how-to-make-gradle-repository-point-to-local-directory) but without success as gradle is excepting a maven repo structure with some pom.xml files.

So how could I achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rethinking the problem and studying a bit more gradle/maven I found the solution.

Just execute the task `gradle publishToMavenLocal` in the parent project. Then in the dependent project add `mavenLocal()` to your list of repo. That's all you have to do.

I'm still looking for a way to make gradle build and publish the parent automatically on the child's build. But it's already much more practical like this?