React Native Gradle fails to resolve local maven-repo
I am trying to build a React Native Package which uses an .aar file for the Android. The .aar file is for internal usage only, thus not shared on a public maven repo. I've created the maven repo inside this directory: my-library/android. When I try to build an example app I get an error that the it cannot resolve the library. The my-library/android/build.gradle file looks like this:
buildscript {
...
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url = uri("${rootProject.projectDir}/maven-repo")
    }
  }
}
...
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
  maven {
    url = uri("${rootProject.projectDir}/maven-repo")
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation("com.mylibrary:localoperationsdk:1.0.0@aar")
}

...

This is the error that I am getting:
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.mylibrary:localoperationsdk:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk/1.0.0/localoperationsdk-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk/1.0.0/localoperationsdk-1.0.0.pom
       - example/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk/1.0.0/localoperationsdk-1.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk/1.0.0/localoperationsdk-1.0.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk/1.0.0/localoperationsdk-1.0.0.pom
     Required by:

The error indicates that it is not looking in the right places to resolve the package. It looks on the online repositories and inside the node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/mylibrary/localoperationsdk
What do I need to change to make sure that it is looking in the right place?

I would try to add the protocol prefix file:// to local folders.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25965901/150978
